# Is "best case performance Θ(1) -> running time ≠ Θ(log n)" valid?

Tags: performance, time-complexity, complexity-theory, big-o

This is an argument for justifying that the running time of an algorithm can't be considered `Θ(f(n))` but should be `O(f(n))` instead.

E.g. this question about binary search: [Is binary search theta log (n) or big O log(n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154402/is-binary-search-theta-log-n-or-big-o-logn)

MartinStettner's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5154457/4644009) is even more confusing.

Consider `*-case` performances:

Best-case performance: Θ(1)
Average-case performance: Θ(log n)
Worst-case performance: Θ(log n)

He then quotes *Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest: "Introduction to Algorithms"*:

> What we mean when we say "the running time is O(n^2)" is that the worst-case running time (which is a function of n) is O(n^2) ...

Doesn't this suggest the terms `running time` and `worst-case running time` are synonymous?

Also, if `running time` refers to a function with natural input `f(n)`, then there has to be `Θ` class which contains it, e.g. `Θ(f(n))`, right? This indicates that you are obligated to use `O` notation only when the running time is not known very precisely (i.e. only an upper bound is known).

Comment: This question is probably more suited for [the Computer Science community](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: should i delete it and repost it there?

Comment: Difficult to say, big-o questions do get answered here, but since this gets pretty deep, you may have more success over at Computer Science.

Comment: vuplea: yes. And that "best case" in question doesn't really mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `O(f(n))` that means that the running time of your algorithm is bounded above by a function `c*f(n)` where `c` is a constant. That also means that that your algorithm can complete in much less number of steps than `c*f(n)`. We often use the Big-O notation because we want to include the possibility that the algorithm completes faster than we indicate. On the other hand, `Theta(f(n))` means that the algorithm always completes in `c*f(n)` steps. Binary search is `O(log(n))` because usually it will complete in `log(n)` steps, but *could* complete in one step if you get lucky (best-case performance).

Answer (score 0):

I get always confused, if I read about running times.

For me a *running time* is the time an implementation of an algorithm needs to be executed on a computer. This can be differ in many ways and so is a complicated thing.

So I think *complexity* of an algorithm is a better word.

Now, **the** complexity is (in most cases) a worst-case-complexity. If you know an upper bound for the worst case, you also know that it can only get better in other cases.

So, if you know, that there exist some (maybe trivial) cases, where your algorithm does only a few  (constant number) steps and stops, you don't have to care about an lower bound and so you (normaly) use an upper bound in big-`O` or little-`o` notation.

If you do your calculations carfully, you can also use the `Θ` notation.

But notice: all complexities only hold on the cases they are attached to. This means: If you make assumtions like *"Input is a best case"*, this effects your calculation and also the resulting complexity. In the case of binary search you posted the complexity for three different assumtions.
You can generalize it by saying: *"The complexity of Binary Search is in `O(log n)`"*, since `Θ(log n)` means "`Ω(log n)` and `O(log n)`" and `O(1)` is a subset of `O(log n)`.

To summerize:
- If you know the very precise function for the complexity, you can give the complexity in `Θ`-notation
- If you want to get an overall upper bound, you have to use `O`-notation, until the lower bound over all input cases does not differ from the upper bound.
- In most cases you have to use the `O`-notation, since the algorithms are too complex to get a close upper and lower bound.